# after submiting form data it show's the following problem

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets

An Exception has occurred! `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 1.`

Comment: Check the sql statement.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `PreparedStatement` with at least one valueholder `?`. When you execute it without having set the valueholder with a value using one of the `PreparedStatement`'s setter methods, then you will get this exception. To solve this you obviously need to set the value with the desired value, e.g.

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, value);
```

Or if you don't need it at all, then just remove it from the SQL string or create another one for this specific purpose.

For more about `PreparedStatement`s, consult the [JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).